# Python dictionary of dump tree list items

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tree

I have a hierarchical structure/tree, which I converted to list presenting (levels, items).
I need to create some loop, which will create dictionary within dictionary of  items presenting levels of tree which could be applicable on other trees with different levels, items.

Dump tree structure:

```
(0, 'Job=XYZ')
    (1, 'Input Options Display')
    (1, 'Abend S=0C7 (DEMO)')
        (2, 'Abending Statement')
            (3, 'Procedure DEMO')
                (4, 'Variables')
            (3, 'Storage')
        (2, 'Program DEMO2')
            (3, 'Storage')
    (1, 'Execution Summary')
```

Expected dictionary something like:

```
{Job=XYZ: 'Input Options Display', 'Abend S=0C7 (DEMO)':{'Abending Statement': 'Procedure DEMO' ... # and so on
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dump tree"?

Comment: dump tree = hierarchical structure of dump(program). 
(0, 'Job=XYZ') = (tree level, 'item')

Comment: Your expected output is a little confusing because on the one hand the `0` level item 'Job' becomes a key, but the `1` level item 'Input' becomes a value. On the other hand the next `1` level item 'Abend' is a key.

Comment: to be honest I am not even sure how that output dictionary should look like ... my target is to have a dictionary, which will reflect the structure of the tree based on levels, levels will be omitted from the output dictionary. Levels(numbers) represent just hierarchy. 
So 'Job=XYZ' is a parent and has children 'Input Options Display', 'Abend S=0C7 (DEMO) which could have or not children ... and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out how to use a dictionary for your hierarchical data, but instead I figured out a hierarchical list:

```
src = [(0, 'Job=XYZ'),
    (1, 'Input Options Display'),
    (1, 'Abend S=0C7 (DEMO)'),
        (2, 'Abending Statement'),
            (3, 'Procedure DEMO'),
                (4, 'Variables'),
            (3, 'Storage'),
        (2, 'Program DEMO2'),
            (3, 'Storage'),
    (1, 'Execution Summary') ]

print(src)

top = []
current = top
current_level = 0
next = None

stack = [current]

for level,item in src:
    if level is not current_level:
        while len(stack) <= level:
            stack.append(None)
        if level > current_level:
            stack[current_level] = current
            current = next
        if level < current_level:
            current = stack[level]
    next = []
    current.append((item,next))
    current_level = level

print(top)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 'Job=XYZ'), (1, 'Input Options Display'), (1, 'Abend S=0C7 (DEMO)'), (2, 'Abending Statement'), (3, 'Procedure DEMO'), (4, 'Variables'), (3, 'Storage'), (2, 'Program DEMO2'), (3, 'Storage'), (1, 'Execution Summary')]
[('Job=XYZ', [('Input Options Display', []), ('Abend S=0C7 (DEMO)', [('Abending Statement', [('Procedure DEMO', [('Variables', [])]), ('Storage', [])]), ('Program DEMO2', [('Storage', [])])]), ('Execution Summary', [])])]
```

`src` is your original data transformed to a list of tuples.
The output shows first `src`, then the transformed data.

The output data structure is a list of tuples where each tuple is the string from your source and a sub list. Each sub list is of course a list of tuples with the same format. (An empty sub list indicates a leaf item).

Comment: Thank you very much! with just small changes of the script it generates dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example with a dictionary as output, but it would be quite a complex structure:

```
# the input list
my_list = [(0, 'Job=XY2'),
           (1, 'Input Options Display'),
           (1, 'Abend S=0C7 (DEMO)'),
           (2, 'Abending Statement'),
           (3, 'Procedure DEMO'),
           (4, 'Variables'),
           (3, 'Storage'),
           (2, 'Program DEMO2'),
           (3, 'Storage'),
           (1, 'Execution Summary')]

def return_dict(key, current_level, l):
    d = {}
    d[key] = []
    for i, (level, element) in enumerate(l):        
        if level == current_level+1 and i+1 < len(l):
            # not the last one
            if l[i+1][0] == level+1:
                # deeper level exist
                d[key].append(return_dict(element, level, l[i+1:]))
            else:
                if element not in d[key]:
                    d[key].append(element)
        else:
            # last one           
            if level == current_level+1:
                d[key].append(element)
    return d

result = return_dict(my_list[0][1], my_list[0][0], my_list[1:])
print(result)
```

The output format is as follows:

- (1) Dictionary, value is always a list
- (2) a list has two types of elements

  - (a) string value if no sub-level exist
  - (b) dictionary if sub-level exist, and this dictionary complies with rule (1)

output:

```
{'Job=XY2': ['Input Options Display', {'Abend S=0C7 (DEMO)': [{'Abending Statement': [{'Procedure DEMO': ['Variables']}, 'Storage']}, {'Program DEMO2': ['Storage']}]}, 'Execution Summary']}
```

you can look at Level 1, being a list with 3 elements of which the first and last element are strings, and the second element is a dictionary.

```
{'Job=XY2': 
    [
        'Input Options Display', 
        {'Abend S=0C7 (DEMO)': [{'Abending Statement': [{'Procedure DEMO': ['Variables']}, 'Storage']}, {'Program DEMO2': ['Storage']}]}, 
        'Execution Summary'
    ]
}
```

If you break down that dictionary element 2 of level 1, you get he following structure, a dictionary with a 2 element list as value, containing dictionaries:

```
{'Abend S=0C7 (DEMO)': 
    [
        {'Abending Statement': [{'Procedure DEMO': ['Variables']}, 'Storage']}, 
        {'Program DEMO2': ['Storage']}
    ]
}
```

Break this level down further, you get this structure:

```
{'Abending Statement': 
    [
        {'Procedure DEMO': ['Variables']}, 
        'Storage'
    ]
}       


{'Program DEMO2': 
    ['Storage']
}
```

To retrieve any value:

- (1) call the key of the top-level, list as result
- (2) enumerate list, or index list

  - (a) if element of list is string, then this is the value
  - (b) if element is dictionary, repeat (1)

example, to get your "Procedure DEMO" value:

```
value = result['Job=XY2'][1]['Abend S=0C7 (DEMO)'][0]['Abending Statement'][0]['Procedure DEMO'][0]
print(value)
```

output:

```
Variables
```